# weight visualization of 3d convolutional kernel

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, visualization

I am using  3d kernel of size 3x3x3 for the convoution layer and would like to plot the weights of the layer.

Since plotting in 3d is not possible i tried to split the kernels into 3 3×3 for plotting.
Is this approach correct?

The conv layer consists of 5 layers #model.add(layers.Conv3D(5, (3, 3, 3), padding=’same’))

Please find below the code I used to plot the weights

```
from keras.models import load_model
mymodel = load_model(‘model.hdf5′)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# load the model

# retrieve weights from the 1st conv layer layer
filters, biases = mymodel.layers[0].get_weights()
# normalize filter values to 0-1 so we can visualize them
f_min, f_max = filters.min(), filters.max()
filters = (filters – f_min) / (f_max – f_min)
#shape of filters (3, 3, 3, 1, 5)
n_filters, ix = 5, 1
for i in range(n_filters):
# get the filter
f = filters[:,:, :, :, i]
f = f[:,:,:,0]
# kernel shape 3x3x3 but to plot it converting into 3 3×3 filters
for j in range(3):
# specify subplot and turn of axis
ax = plt.subplot(n_filters, 3, ix)
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
# plot filter channel in grayscale
plt.imshow(f[:, :, j], cmap=’gray’)
ix += 1
# show the figure
plt.show()
```

Is this method correct or is there any better way in which this can be done?

Looking forward to your reply

Answer (score 2):

The code you have used is good for displaying the Conv2D Convolution kernel in gray scale OR Conv3D Convolution kernel in Color(because of the depth of kernel causing merge of three gray scale images).

You need to modify the code as below to make it reusable for printing the Conv3d Convolution kernel in Gray scale. You have to modify the `Depth`, `outgoing_channels` and `incoming_channels` in the code as per the Conv3D layers kernel you are printing.

**Modified Code -**

```
# normalize filter values to 0-1 so we can visualize them
f_min, f_max = filters.min(), filters.max()
filters = (filters - f_min) / (f_max - f_min)
# plot first few filters
# n_filters = outgoing channels
outgoing_channels = 2
n_filters, ix = outgoing_channels, 1
for i in range(n_filters):
    # get the filter
    f = filters[:, :, :, :, i]
    # plot each channel separately
    # Range of incoming channels
    incoming_channels = 4
    for j in range(incoming_channels):
        # Range of Depth of the kernel .i.e. 3
        Depth = 3
        for k in range(Depth):
            # specify subplot and turn of axis
            ax = pyplot.subplot((outgoing_channels*3), incoming_channels, ix)
            ax.set_xticks([])
            ax.set_yticks([])
            # plot filter channel in grayscale
            pyplot.imshow(f[:, :, k,j], cmap='gray')
            ix += 1
# show the figure
pyplot.show()
```

---

**End-to-End Example:** This example explains

1. Builds a Model having Conv3D Layer.
2. Calculation of Params of  a layer and breaking them to understand the layer weights and bias weights.
3. print the convolution kernel of the layer.

---

```
# (1) Importing dependency
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Conv3D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1000)

# (2) Get Data
import tflearn.datasets.oxflower17 as oxflower17
x, y = oxflower17.load_data(one_hot=True)
x = np.expand_dims(x,-1)

# (3) Create a sequential model
model = Sequential()

# 1st Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv3D(filters=2, input_shape=(224,224,3,1), kernel_size=(3,3,3), strides=(4,4,4), padding='Same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv3D(filters=4, kernel_size=(3,3,3), strides=(1,1,1), padding='Same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv3D(filters=2, kernel_size=(3,3,3), strides=(1,1,1), padding='Same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# Passing it to a dense layer
model.add(Flatten())
# 1st Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(17))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()

# (4) Compile 
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(x, y, batch_size=64, epochs= 4, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True)
```

Output of the code -

```
Model: "sequential_6"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv3d_10 (Conv3D)           (None, 56, 56, 1, 2)      56        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_26 (Activation)   (None, 56, 56, 1, 2)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_11 (Conv3D)           (None, 56, 56, 1, 4)      220       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_27 (Activation)   (None, 56, 56, 1, 4)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv3d_12 (Conv3D)           (None, 56, 56, 1, 2)      218       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_28 (Activation)   (None, 56, 56, 1, 2)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_6 (Flatten)          (None, 6272)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 100)               627300    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_29 (Activation)   (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 17)                1717      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_30 (Activation)   (None, 17)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 629,511
Trainable params: 629,511
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 1088 samples, validate on 272 samples
Epoch 1/4
1088/1088 [==============================] - 2s 1ms/step - loss: 2.8274 - acc: 0.0597 - val_loss: 2.8071 - val_acc: 0.0551
Epoch 2/4
1088/1088 [==============================] - 1s 522us/step - loss: 2.7204 - acc: 0.1728 - val_loss: 2.6962 - val_acc: 0.1360
Epoch 3/4
1088/1088 [==============================] - 1s 517us/step - loss: 2.4334 - acc: 0.3612 - val_loss: 2.4341 - val_acc: 0.2316
Epoch 4/4
1088/1088 [==============================] - 1s 518us/step - loss: 1.9551 - acc: 0.4577 - val_loss: 2.1545 - val_acc: 0.3309
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7ff4bba5e5f8>
```

Lets print the convolution kernels for below layer (3rd Conv3D layer in the model) -

```
conv3d_12 (Conv3D)            (None, 56, 56, 1, 2)      218       
_________________________________________________________________
```

Param calculated as follows -

> Params of a Conv3D layer - “(n*m*l*k*3) + k ”
>
> - The filter size is “n*m”.
> - “l” incoming_channels as the input. In our case it is 4.
> - “k” outgoing_channels as output. In our case it is 2.

Thus params = (3*3*4*2*3)+2  = 218

`Params` are `layer weights` + `Bias Weights`. So removing biases .i.e. 2(biases are equal to features map or channel as output). Thus total `layer weights` = 218 - 2 = 216. **So we should be getting 216/9 = 24 gray scale images of 3*3.**

I have made the code generic so that it is reusable. You just need to modify `Depth`, `outgoing_channels` and `incoming_channels` which will fit the all the gray scale images of that layer. In our case `outgoing_channels`=2 and `incoming_channels`=4.

Run the Visualization Code -

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

# retrieve weights from the 3rd Conv3D layer
filters, biases = model.layers[4].get_weights()

# normalize filter values to 0-1 so we can visualize them
f_min, f_max = filters.min(), filters.max()
filters = (filters - f_min) / (f_max - f_min)
# plot first few filters
# n_filters = outgoing channels
outgoing_channels = 2
n_filters, ix = outgoing_channels, 1
for i in range(n_filters):
    # get the filter
    f = filters[:, :, :, :, i]
    # plot each channel separately
    # Range of incoming channels
    incoming_channels = 4
    for j in range(incoming_channels):
        # Range of Depth of the kernel .i.e. 3
        Depth = 3
        for k in range(Depth):
            # specify subplot and turn of axis
            ax = pyplot.subplot((outgoing_channels*3), incoming_channels, ix)
            ax.set_xticks([])
            ax.set_yticks([])
            # plot filter channel in grayscale
            pyplot.imshow(f[:, :, k,j], cmap='gray')
            ix += 1
# show the figure
pyplot.show()
```

Output of the Visualization code -

[image]

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Arjun - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.