# Visualizing the Gradients as heat map in Tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am working on a task to generate heatmap by guided backpropagation. I have overridden the original Relu and obtained the gradient for each parameter. However, I am not sure what should I do next. Your assistance is appreciated! Thank you!

Here is my code:

I first use `@tf.RegisterGradient("GuidedRelu")` like:

```
def _GuidedReluGrad(op, grad):
    gate_f = tf.cast(op.outputs[0] > 0, "float32")
    gate_R = tf.cast(grad > 0, "float32")
    return gate_f * gate_R * grad
```

Then, I obtained grads by:

```
with g.gradient_override_map({"Relu": "GuidedRelu"}):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = self.net(tf.cast(img, dtype=tf.float32))
        xentropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            labels=tf.cast(
                tf.one_hot(predicted_class, depth=1000), dtype=tf.int32
            ),
            logits=logits,
        )
        reduced = tf.reduce_mean(xentropy)
        grads = tape.gradient(reduced, self.net.trainable_variables)
```

I found the grad for the first layer has shape (7, 7, 3, 64). But I don't know how to use this grad to generate a heatmap that has similar size to the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is similar to kernel visualization of the layer. Below is an example where I am visualizing `Conv2D` layer having `(7, 7, 4, 4)` shape. `(7, 7, 4, 4)` means the layer has `7*7` `Kernels` with `4` `incoming filters`(filters of previous layer) and last `4` is the `outgoing filters` of this layer.

So in your case, `(7, 7, 3, 64)` means you have `7*7` `Kernels` with `3` `incoming filters`(as it is your first layer, guessing your input is a color image) and `64` is your layers `filters`.

For your reference, I have print all the Convolution layers of my model. I am using the same code in visualization code to get the filter shapes of last layer .i.e. `conv2d_3 (7, 7, 4, 4)` and use it for visualization -

```
# summarize filter shapes
for layer in model.layers:
    # check for convolutional layer
    if 'conv' in layer.name:
      # get filter weights
      filters, biases = layer.get_weights()
      print(layer.name, filters.shape)
```

**Output -**

```
conv2d_1 (3, 3, 3, 2)
conv2d_2 (3, 3, 2, 4)
conv2d_3 (7, 7, 4, 4)
```

We shall Visualize `conv2d_3 (7, 7, 4, 4)` as it is similar to your requirement. So basically we should have (`incoming filters * outgoing filters` = `16`)16 images of `7*7` size.

**Code for Visualization -** You need to modify `incoming_filters` and `outgoing_filters` which are filters of previous layer(if it is first layer then the channel size of image) and filters of this layer respectively.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

# filters will have details of last Conv layer .i.e. conv2d_3 (7, 7, 4, 4)
for layer in model.layers:
    # check for convolutional layer
    if 'conv' in layer.name:
      # get filter weights
      filters, biases = layer.get_weights()

# Fix the figure size
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))

# Normalize filter values to 0-1 so we can visualize them
f_min, f_max = filters.min(), filters.max()
filters = (filters - f_min) / (f_max - f_min)
outgoing_filters, ix = 4, 1 
for i in range(outgoing_filters):
    # get the filter
    f = filters[:, :, :, i]
    # plot each channel separately
    incoming_filters = 4 
    for j in range(incoming_filters):
        # specify subplot and turn of axis
        ax = pyplot.subplot(incoming_filters, outgoing_filters, ix)
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        # plot filter channel 
        # Use cmap='gray' for Gray scale image
        pyplot.imshow(f[:, :, j]) 
        ix += 1

# show the figure
pyplot.show()
```

**Output -**

[image]

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

---

**Edit -** Made some more effort to capture gradients after every epoch and visualize them. Used below code to capture gradients after every epoch. I am using old way to capture gradients in Tensorflow 1.15.0 and not using `tf.GradientTape`. If you would like to know How to capture gradient using `tf.GradientTape` then you can refer our answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980124/full-batch-gradient-descent-with-tf-gradienttape-oom-error).

In the below program, `gradient` is the `array` that has gradients captured after every epoch for every layer.

**Code -**

```
# (1) Importing dependency
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Conv3D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1000)

# (2) Get Data
import tflearn.datasets.oxflower17 as oxflower17
x, y = oxflower17.load_data(one_hot=True)

# (3) Create a sequential model
model = Sequential()

# 1st Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=2, input_shape=(224,224,3), kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(4,4), padding='Same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='Same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(7,7), strides=(1,1), padding='Same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# Passing it to a dense layer
model.add(Flatten())
# 1st Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(100))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(17))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()

# (4) Compile 
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
epoch_gradient = []

def get_gradient_func(model):
    grads = K.gradients(model.total_loss, model.trainable_weights)
    inputs = model.model._feed_inputs + model.model._feed_targets + model.model._feed_sample_weights
    func = K.function(inputs, grads)
    return func

# Define the Required Callback Function
class GradientCalcCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
      get_gradient = get_gradient_func(model)
      grads = get_gradient([x, y, np.ones(len(y))])
      epoch_gradient.append(grads)

epoch = 4

model.fit(x, y, batch_size=64, epochs= epoch, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[GradientCalcCallback()])

# (7) Convert to a 2 dimensiaonal array of (epoch, gradients) type
gradient = np.asarray(epoch_gradient)
print("Total number of epochs run:", epoch)
print("Gradient Array has the shape:",gradient.shape)
```

**Output -**

```
TensorFlow 1.x selected.
Using TensorFlow backend.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tflearn/helpers/summarizer.py:9: The name tf.summary.merge is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.merge instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py:25: The name tf.summary.FileWriter is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tflearn/collections.py:13: The name tf.GraphKeys is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tflearn/config.py:123: The name tf.get_collection is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_collection instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tflearn/config.py:129: The name tf.add_to_collection is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.add_to_collection instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tflearn/config.py:131: The name tf.assign is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign instead.

Downloading Oxford 17 category Flower Dataset, Please wait...
100.0% 60276736 / 60270631
('Succesfully downloaded', '17flowers.tgz', 60270631, 'bytes.')
File Extracted
Starting to parse images...
Parsing Done!
WARNING:tensorflow:From /tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1630: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 56, 56, 2)         56        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 56, 56, 2)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 56, 56, 4)         76        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 56, 56, 4)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 56, 56, 4)         788       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 56, 56, 4)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 12544)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 100)               1254500   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 17)                1717      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 17)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 1,257,137
Trainable params: 1,257,137
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:422: The name tf.global_variables is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.global_variables instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:431: The name tf.is_variable_initialized is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.is_variable_initialized instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:438: The name tf.variables_initializer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer instead.

Train on 1088 samples, validate on 272 samples
Epoch 1/4
1088/1088 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 2.8055 - accuracy: 0.0846 - val_loss: 2.7566 - val_accuracy: 0.1176
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py:111: UserWarning: `Sequential.model` is deprecated. `Sequential` is a subclass of `Model`, you can just use your `Sequential` instance directly.
  warnings.warn('`Sequential.model` is deprecated. '
Epoch 2/4
1088/1088 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 2.3974 - accuracy: 0.3263 - val_loss: 2.5707 - val_accuracy: 0.2132
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py:111: UserWarning: `Sequential.model` is deprecated. `Sequential` is a subclass of `Model`, you can just use your `Sequential` instance directly.
  warnings.warn('`Sequential.model` is deprecated. '
Epoch 3/4
1088/1088 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 1.5953 - accuracy: 0.5506 - val_loss: 2.4076 - val_accuracy: 0.2684
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py:111: UserWarning: `Sequential.model` is deprecated. `Sequential` is a subclass of `Model`, you can just use your `Sequential` instance directly.
  warnings.warn('`Sequential.model` is deprecated. '
Epoch 4/4
1088/1088 [==============================] - 5s 5ms/step - loss: 0.8699 - accuracy: 0.7812 - val_loss: 2.5698 - val_accuracy: 0.3162
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py:111: UserWarning: `Sequential.model` is deprecated. `Sequential` is a subclass of `Model`, you can just use your `Sequential` instance directly.
  warnings.warn('`Sequential.model` is deprecated. '
Total number of epochs run: 4
Gradient Array has the shape: (4, 10)
```

**Visualization -**

Lets Visualize `gradient[0][4]`, .i.e. `[0]` means the 1st epoch and `[4]` means fifth later of the model.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

filters = gradient[0][4]

# Fix the figure size
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))

# Normalize filter values to 0-1 so we can visualize them
f_min, f_max = filters.min(), filters.max()
filters = (filters - f_min) / (f_max - f_min)
outgoing_filters, ix = 4, 1 
for i in range(outgoing_filters):
    # get the filter
    f = filters[:, :, :, i]
    # plot each channel separately
    incoming_filters = 4 
    for j in range(incoming_filters):
        # specify subplot and turn of axis
        ax = pyplot.subplot(incoming_filters, outgoing_filters, ix)
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        # plot filter channel 
        # Use cmap='gray' for Gray scale image
        pyplot.imshow(f[:, :, j]) 
        ix += 1

# show the figure
pyplot.show()
```

**Output -**

[image]

If you would like to Visualize `Conv3D` then refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456336/weight-visualization-of-3d-convolutional-kernel/61817472#61817472).

Hope this answers your question in detail. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Guanfang Dong - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Thank you so much it's very clear and detail! Thank you so much for your help!